# Integral form of a limit

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, exponential-function

Consider:
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow\infty} \sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} \frac{1}{n^k}$$
One might consider using the binomial expansion to obtain:
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n $$
Which equals $e$.
My question is: How can I write the first limit as an integral over some interval of some function? Is it an elementary function? Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking to write the sum as a Riemann sum?